# How to keep images locked at specific height within Bootstrap container

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have built the following Christmas e-card:

http://www.christmas.drcrittall.com

As can be seen, the central image changes every 3 seconds or so, cycling through an array sent from the back-end server side. However, as can be seen, the images are constantly changing size and causing the central container (black border) to expand out into other parts of the page. I was wondering how I can prevent this from happening and keep the images all locked in the same position ie a height of 60% (#middle) of the page. Please see below:

**CSS:**

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;                
}               
/* Background image for website */ 
body {
      /*background: url("images/crumpled.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;*/
      background: url("../img/crumpled.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      /*margin-bottom:5%;*/                                 
}
#header {
    height:20%;
    /*
    border-style: solid; 
    border-color:red;
    padding:0px;  */                    
}
#middle {
    height:60%;
    /* border-style: solid; 
    border-color:green;*/
}
#cap {
    height:20%;
    /*border-style: solid; 
    border-color:blue;
    /* Previously the click here text was overflowing out of this div. See here to see how to deal with this: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/ */
    /*overflow:auto;*/.
}
#form {
    min-height:20%; /* Setting min-height of white-space beneath body enables container to expand with the form as it gets bigger */ 
    display:none;  /* This div is initially hidden until click button which activates jquery animation */
}
#main_image {
    width:100%;
    max-height:100%; 
}
#candle_image {
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
}
#top_paper {
    width:100%;
    max-height:100%; 
}
/* Make row height and columns fill entire height of containers */
.row, .col-md-6, .col-md-4, .col-md-6, .col-md-12, .col-md-8, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, {
    height:100%; 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class = "container-fluid center_font" id = "header">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <font id = "dear"> Merry Christmas! </font>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "container-fluid center_font" id = "middle">
        <div class = "row" style = "border-style:solid; border-color:black;">
            <div class = "col-md-3" id = "holly_1" style = "padding-top:10%;">
                <img src = "../img/candles.png" id = "candle_image" class = "img-fluid">    
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-6 col-xs-12" style = "border-style:solid; border-color:yellow;">
                <img src = "" id = "main_image" class = "img-circle">
            </div> 
            <div class = "col-md-3" id = "holly_2" style = "padding-top:10%;">
                <img src = "../img/candles.png" id = "candle_image" class = "img-fluid">    
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class = "container-fluid" id = "cap" style = "border-style:solid; border-color:green;">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 center_font">                  
                <font id = "dear" style = "font-size:45px;"> Love from Matthew</font>
            </div> 
            <div class = "col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 center_font">
                <a href = "#" id = "reveal">
                    <font id = "dear" class = "fiddle" style = "font-size: 20px;">Click Me</font>
                </a> 
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div> 
</body>
```

Any help to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use viewport height units: `vh`

```css
#main_image {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 60vh;
}
```

Comment: because of `#header {
    height: 20%;}` in the top of screen and `#cap {
    height: 20%;`} in the bottom.

Comment: `60vh` is equal to 60%  of vieport height and it lets image height to avoid from  binding to height of parent container.